# PHP sudo: a terminal is required to read the password

Tags: php, linux, shell, sudo

I have a script which I want to call from my PHP code. The following is the script file I have:

**listwifi.sh**

```
sudo iwlist wlp1s0 scan | grep SSID
```

To this I've also given executable permission by using `sudo chmod +x listwifi.sh`

The following I've added at the end pf my sudoers file (using visudo):

```
apache ALL = NOPASSWD: /var/www/html/mypath/osscripts/listwifi.sh *
www-data ALL = NOPASSWD: /var/www/html/mypath/osscripts/listwifi.sh *
```

I had also tried with :

```
apache ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin /var/www/html/mypath/osscripts/listwifi.sh *
www-data ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin /var/www/html/mypath/osscripts/listwifi.sh *
```

I'm using the following PHP code to call this file:

```
exec(getenv('BASE_DIR') . "/osscripts/listwifi.sh", $output);
var_dump($output);
```

But I keep getting the following error:

> sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper

How can I make PHP execute this file as root without having to enter the password?

Comment: Take the `sudo` out of the script and call the script as `sudo /var/www/html/mypath/osscripts/listwifi.sh`

Comment: @sabik Thank you :) That worked. Can you please explain how this works differently than using sudo in the script ?

Comment: The `sudoers` configuration is for the command being invoked via `sudo`, not where it's invoked from...

Comment: @sabik Thanks. Can you put that up as an answer so I can mark it as closed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the `sudo` out of the script and call the script as

```
sudo /var/www/html/mypath/osscripts/listwifi.sh
```

The `sudoers` configuration is for the command being invoked via `sudo`, not where it's invoked from...